# Dependency Injection in C# Web API

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I am trying to create a rest service in C# Web API.

At the moment I'm not considering any DB decisions, hence I'm adding a mock class library.

I'm creating a model interface and implementing the model in the mock class library.

```
public interface IUser
{
    int userId { get; set; }
    string firstName { get; set; }
    string lastName { get; set; }
    string email { get; set; }

    List<IUser> getAllUsers();
    IUser getUser(int ID);
    bool updateUser(IUser user);
    bool deleteUser(int ID);
}
```

and implementing this in the mock class library

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }

    public bool deleteUser(int ID)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<IUser> getAllUsers()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IUser getUser(int ID)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool updateUser(IUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now the mock library references the service application to implement the interface.

Now I need to call the mock implementation from the controller class in the service application.

How do I do that without creating a cyclic dependency. I did some research and came up with a solution that DI is the way to go.

Can someone help me to implement this with code samples?

Many thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/12977743/126014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind which IoC container you might use, I would recommend Ninject.

You need to install the next packages via Nuget:

- [Ninject](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/)
- [Ninject integration for Web Api 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi/)
- [Ninject Web Host for WebApi 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost/)
- [Ninject Web Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/3.2.3)
- [Ninject Web Common Web Host](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost/3.2.3)

Then in the Ninject configuration file NinjectWebCommon.cs in the end of RegisterServices() method add the following code:

```
kernel.Bind<IUser>().To<User>();
```

And now just add IUser as a parameter to the controller class and Ninject will automatically inject it.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

private IUser _user;

     // Ninject will automatically inject a User instance here
     // on controller creation
     public MyController(IUser user)
     {
         _user = user;
     }
}
```

There are different approaches for using Ninject so you can search for other that will fit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

> "Now I need to call the mock implementation from the controller class in the service application."

This doesn't sound right. I think you have a design issue here; why do you need to reference a *mock* implementation of `IUser` from your service application?

- One thing to bear in mind is that *clients own the interface*, so the `IUser` interface does not belong in the Mock class library at all; it should ideally be defined in a totally separate assembly so that both your mock class library *and* your service class library can reference it (and provide their own implementations for it if required).
- This is the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and whilst I agree that a DI library of some kind can help you to manage the implementation of such Inversion of Control, I don't believe that it will help you here in the long run. You will probably still run into the same cyclic reference issues in the container itself.
- Right now I think you first need to look at using the [Stairway Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259414/stairway-pattern-implementation) to get your Dependencies correctly inverted before you look at using any DI libraries

Answer (score 0):

> Now the mock library references the service application to implement the interface.

This is the source of your problem. I would recommend moving the interfaces for your data access layer out into a separate project. Then you can create a project with mock/in memory implementations, and later on add another project with the real implementations.

Another thing is that your `IUser` is the contract for your DTO (data transfer object), but it contains DAO (data access object) methods. Typically you would want to separate these concerns with something like the repository pattern.

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    IEnumerable<IUser> GetAllUsers();
    IUser GetUser(int id);
    ...
}
```

This repository is what you would inject into your API controller.