# Resolving HttpRequestMessage with Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I've tried following advice from existing posts to make `HttpRequestMessage` available as a constructor dependency for services in Web API:

[ASP Web Api - IoC - Resolve HttpRequestMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977743/asp-web-api-ioc-resolve-httprequestmessage)

[Resolving HttpControllerContext with Castle Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854701/resolving-httpcontrollercontext-with-castle-windsor)

This advice works fine *if* all the dependencies *only have one constructor*.  But when a dependency has multiple constructors, dependency resolution fails.

Any ideas how to extend the idea to work with multiple constructors?

=======================

The existing approach is summarised as follows:

First you add the `HttpRequestMessage` as an additional named argument when resolving the controller in your `IHttpControllerActivator`:

```
public IHttpController Create(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
    Type controllerType)
{
    var controller = (IHttpController)container.Resolve(
        controllerType,
        new { request });
```

Then you propagate this argument in the `CreationContext`:

```
public class InlineDependenciesPropagatingDependencyResolver :
    DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    protected override CreationContext RebuildContextForParameter(
        CreationContext current,
        Type parameterType)
    {
        if (parameterType.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            return current;
        }

        return new CreationContext(parameterType, current, true);
    }
}
```

This works fine when all the dependencies only have one constructor.

In my case, I have a hierarchy of dependencies:

- The controller depends on `IServiceA`
- `ServiceA` depends on `IServiceB`
- `ServiceB` depends on `IServiceC`
- `ServiceC` depends on `HttpRequestMessage`

Where `ServiceC` looks like this:

```
public class ServiceC: IServiceC
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage request;

    public ServiceC(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }
```

And `ServiceB` has two constructors:

```
public class ServiceB: IServiceB
{
    public ServiceB(string paramForTests)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public ServiceB(IServiceC serviceC)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

But then Windsor fails to resolve `ServiceC`.

The problem seems to be in the `SelectEligibleConstructor` logic of [DefaultComponentActivator](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/ComponentActivator/DefaultComponentActivator.cs).  It calls into the `CanResolve` method in [DefaultDependencyResolver](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Resolvers/DefaultDependencyResolver.cs) which eventually ends up at:

```
protected virtual bool CanResolveFromKernel(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
{
    if (dependency.ReferencedComponentName != null)
    {
        // User wants to override
        return HasComponentInValidState(dependency.ReferencedComponentName, dependency, context);
    }
    if (dependency.Parameter != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (typeof(IKernel).IsAssignableFrom(dependency.TargetItemType))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (dependency.TargetItemType.IsPrimitiveType())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return HasAnyComponentInValidState(dependency.TargetItemType, dependency, context);
}
```

And then `HasAnyComponentInValidState` just looks at whether `ServiceC` has already been resolved, it doesn't actually check whether it *can be* resolved.

If there is only one constructor, then the code calls the `Resolve` methods, which correctly recursively resolve the dependencies, and ServiceC is available ok.

I don't want to limit my services to only having one constructor (or use the `[DoNotSelect]` attribute to only leave one for Castle to look at).

Any ideas how to inject arguments as I have done, and still have it work with multiple constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way of resolving the `HttpRequestMessage` parameter, which now works.

Just use a factory method to spin up the service with the dependency on `HttpRequestMessage`, where you manually extract the required "request" argument from the context which has been passed down from the controller activator:

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IServiceC>()
                .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, context) => {
                    var request = (HttpRequestMessage)context.AdditionalArguments["request"];
                    var serviceC = new ServiceC(request);
                    return serviceC;
                })
                .LifestyleTransient()
        );
    }
}
```